# Change of Mutual Information in Isolated Quantum Systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, density-operator, time-evolution, correlation-functions

I was reading some publications regarding correlation and mutual information for composite quantum systems.
I noticed that most papers give the expression for the mutual information to be:
$$\Delta I(A:B) = \Delta S(A) + \Delta S(B)$$
Stating that the term $\Delta S(AB)$ must be equal to zero for isolated composite systems undergoing $\rho_{AB}^0 \rightarrow U\rho_{AB}^0U^\dagger = \rho_{AB}^t$.

Why can we say that the entropy for composite systems does not change under unitary transformations?

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: yess, it definitely helped understanding the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly how to understand your notation, but if you ask why the von Neumann entropy of a density matrix does not change under a unitary transformation, then this is due to the fact that a unitary transformation does not change the eigenvalues of the density matrix. Consider a density matrix $\rho\equiv \sum\limits_k \lambda_k P_k$ and the corresponding von Neumann entropy:
$$S_{\mathrm{N}} (\rho) = - \sum\limits_k \lambda_k \, \ln(\lambda_k) \quad .$$

For a unitary $U$, the operator $\rho^\prime \equiv U\,\rho\,U^\dagger$ has the same eigenvalues as $\rho$ and hence $S_{\mathrm{N}} (\rho) = S_{\mathrm{N}} (\rho^\prime)$.